# Javascript Array Selection Via Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dropdownbox

I'm trying to create a webpage that displays details (from an array) about a user selected item from a dropdown list. I'm supposed to add pictures for the final project, but right now I'm trying to get the function in the Javascript to work properly. I have it working for the first item in the drop down list, but when I added the ELSE IF part to test the second one, it keeps selecting the information from the first drop down list selection. I purposely didn't add the rest of the code after that, because I was trying to troubleshoot why the second selection wasn't working.  I should be able to figure out after that. I just don't understand why the second bit of the function isn't wanting to work right. Below is my coding. Let me know where I went wrong/what I could do better. Thanks!

```js
function myArrayFunction () {
 var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex);
 var apple = ["Apple", "fruit", "$1.28/lb"];
 var carrot = ["Carrot", "vegetable", "$1.09/lb"];
 var pepper = ["Pepper", "vegetable", "$2.67/lb"];
 var strawberry = ["Strawberry", "fruit", "$4.59/lb"];
 if(x = apple) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = apple.toString();
 } else if(x = carrot) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = carrot.toString();
  
}
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Produce Information</title>
<meta Charset="utf-8">
</head>
<h1>Produce Information</h1>

<body>



<p>Select a produce from the list and click "submit" to get more information about it.</p>


  <p><select id="mySelect">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
  <option value="pepper">Pepper</option>
  <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
</select></p>
  <p><button onclick="myArrayFunction()">Submit</button>
  <p id="output"></p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="myArrayFunction.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing for equality. You are assigning:

```
x = apple
```

should be

```
x == apple
```

Same goes for the else if statement.

You also have other issues in this...You are trying to check for equality between an array and a number. Or maybe your intentions are to compare whether the selected index is equal to the actual character string: "apple." I have no idea. I doubt this is what your intentions are... Based on what I am assuming, this may be what you are looking for:

```
if(x = apple) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = apple.toString();
    } else if(x = carrot) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = carrot.toString();
}
```

can be

```
switch(x){
  case 0:
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = apple.toString();
   break;
  case 1:
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = carrot.toString();
   break;
  case 2:
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = pepper.toString();
   break;
  case 3:
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strawberry.toString();
   break;
}
```

**This is just a start, you have a lot of cleaning up to do throughout this entire function.**

Comment: Whoops, good catch. I was trying to compare what the user selected with x to get an output for the function using a for loop. I'm pretty new to this, so I still have a ways to go. Thanks for the help. I'll try that and see what I can do now.

Answer (score 0):

A couple simple mistakes.  Use == in place of = and put quotes around what you are testing for.  I'm not familiar with the first line of your function so I replaced it.

```
function myArrayFunction () {
    //var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex);
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var apple = ["Apple", "fruit", "$1.28/lb"];
    var carrot = ["Carrot", "vegetable", "$1.09/lb"];
    var pepper = ["Pepper", "vegetable", "$2.67/lb"];
    var strawberry = ["Strawberry", "fruit", "$4.59/lb"];
    if (x == "apple") {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = apple.toString();
    } else if(x == "carrot") {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = carrot.toString();        
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to replace the middle part with an object

```
function myArrayFunction () {
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var fruit_veggies={
        apple:["Apple", "fruit", "$1.28/lb"],
        carrot:["Carrot", "vegetable", "$1.09/lb"],
        pepper:["Pepper", "vegetable", "$2.67/lb"],
        strawberry:["Strawberry", "fruit", "$4.59/lb"]  
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = fruit_veggies[x].toString();
}
```